# CacheEvict from Iterable collection

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I have 2 method like this :

first, i'm get users deposit

```
@Override
@Transactional
@Cacheable(value = "deposits")
public Set<Deposit> getUserDeposit() {

    User user = userRepository.findOneByUsername(
            securityHolder.getUserDetails().getUsername());

    Set<Deposit> deposits = user.getBalance().getDeposits();
    return deposits;
}
```

and second, when save task entity which contain a one deposit as relationship i want evict from cache deposit by id :

(spring data interface)

```
@CacheEvict(value = "deposits", key = "#entity.deposit.id", condition = "#entity != null")
<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entity);
```

but that no work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CacheEvict` works on an item not an iterator on items. There's a smell in your code: if you look at the SpEL expressions they are written as entity was the object to evict while its parameter type clearly says it's different.

There is another issue with the get. You are putting something in the cache with no key and the content depends on the connected user. You should make that information part of the key. Right now each new call overrides the content of the cache. Worse if you cache one user and then call that method with a different logged in user it'll get the deposit of another user!